# How to display five rows?

Tags: php, mysql, rows

How can I use PHP to show five rows from a MySQL database, then create a new line and show another five, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [LIMIT clause](http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm) if you want to limit the amount of results returned from the query.

If you want to print an `<hr/>` after every fifth record you can check it via the [modulus operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php):

```
$counter = 1;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rst)) {

 // print $row stuff

 if ($counter % 5 == 0)
    print "<hr />";

 $counter++;

}
```

Basically, we have a variable used to count how many records we've printed. Once that counter can be divided by five, and leave no remainder, we print our horizontal-rule.

Comment: No need to reset the counter. Let it increment and at least you have potentially useful information at the end of the loop, which is the total number of rows. Resetting the counter doesn't do anything useful other than taking up more cputime. And no matter how much the int grows, an int will always take up the same amount of space in memory weather it's 1, 100, or 1,000,000.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may be helpful:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);  
if($result) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
        if(++$i%5==0 && $i>0) {
          /* do the extra thing... new line some styles */
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Err.. you mean something like:

```
SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE ... LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$total = 20;//get total number here;
$limit = 5;
for($i = 0;$i< $total/$limit;$i++)
{
    $sql = $result = $rows = "";
    $start = $limit * $i;
    $sql = "select * from m_table order by id desc limit $start,$limit";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        //print the result here;
    }
}
```

You can fetch 5 rows every time from mysql without fetching all the rows at once.